# ace datatable groupBy column breaks when using pagination

Tags: jsf, datatable, pagination, icefaces

Hope someone can help me out with this.

The issue is as follows:
I have a datatable that displays user variables. One of the columns on the table is grouped to show the variable type in one cell for all the variables that share the same type, which can be many, and since there could be so many I enabled datatable pagination.

However, the issue comes when the variables of a said type exceed the rows per page number and are splitted among various pages. In that case, when I navigate to the next page, the information meant to be in the grouped column is lost and the data from the other columns is moved one column to the left, therefore showing an incorrect column-value relationship (the last column of the table therefore left blank).

Here is the code for my datatable and grouped column

```
     <ace:dataTable value="#{bean.variables}" paginator="true" filterEvent="enter" selectionMode="single" id="variableTable" rowSelectListener="#{bean.showVariable}" var="variable" rows="10" paginatorPosition="bottom" >

    <ace:column groupBy="#{variable.type}" headerText="#{basicBundleBase.type}">
            <h:outputText value="#{variable.type}" />
    </ace:column>

    <ace:column groupOn="#{variable.name}" headerText="#{basicBundleBase.name}">
            <h:outputText value="#{variable.name}" />
    </ace:column>

    <ace:column headerText="#{basicBundleBase.description}">
            <h:outputText value="#{variable.description}" />
    </ace:column>
```

I've searched a lot around but haven't got any clue on how to solve this; checked on ace:column and ace:dataTable tags but just can't seem to figure out how to make it work. That's why I came here to ask for some help.

Hope someone can give me a hand with this issue!

Thanks in advance for your help and time!

Cheers

Tsuru